# How can this function and its first derivative be undefined at a point, but its second derivative be defined?

Tags: calculus

$\frac{-5}{x-2}$
at $2$.
I am thinking that we cannot get a slope at a point where the function doesn't exist, and it cant count as a min/max point if there is no point there!

But even if there is an asymptote there, it can still count as an inflection point for the second derivative due to it technically being concave up and then concave down after the asymptote.

Am I correct? Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of an inflection point?

Comment: @ramose Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can calculate and consider $f''(x)$ for $x>2$ and for $x<2$ but since $f(x)$ is not defined at $x=2$ that point can't be considered an inflection point since [**by definition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point#Definition) "*Inflection points are the points of the curve where the curvature changes its sign while a tangent exists*".